# Retrofit: onFailure: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am writing an android application using retrofit and an laravel backend api.
My problem is: i want to get back the users with the api, this works fine as it looks in the chrome:inspector, but logcat shows: **onFailure: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $**

my interface:

```
public interface ApiService {

    @POST("register")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<AccessToken> register(@Field("name") String name, @Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);

    @POST("login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<AccessToken> login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

    @GET("users")
    Call<UserResponse> users();

}
```

My Response Class

```
import java.util.List;

public class UserResponse {

    List<User> data;

    public List<User> getData() {
        return data;
    }
```

My user Model

```
public class User {

    int id;
    String name;
    String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

And my api call:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_get_user)
    void getUsers() {
        call = service.users();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    username.setText(response.body().getData().get(0).getName());
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(GameActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    tokenManager.deleteToken();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

Hopefully you can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Invalid json parsing. you are trying to parse an array as object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "List" ad shown below:-

```
**Api interface**
```

public interface ApiService {

```
@POST("register")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<List<AccessToken>> register(@Field("name") String name, @Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);

@POST("login")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<List<AccessToken>> login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);

@GET("users")
Call<List<UserResponse>> users();
```

}

**api call:**

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_get_user)
    void getUsers() {
        call = service.users();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<UserResponse>> call, Response<List<UserResponse>> response) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    username.setText(response.body().getData().get(0).getName());
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(GameActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    tokenManager.deleteToken();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<UserResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: But know it gives me a null pointer exception when i want to access the data :(

Comment: you can check your error code by printing response.code() if you are getting response but not response.body() or now you can get your  data by response.body().get(0).getName()

Comment: i tried this **response.body().get(0).getName()**, but it says getName() could not be resolved

response.code() returned 200

Comment: okay I got my initial error... in my laravel api I returned response()->json($users) instead of response()->json(**['data'=>$users]**)

Answer (score 0):

You should check json that you are sending from your backend api. Probably you are sending an object from your backend api for `@GET("users")` api call but you want to parse it's response as `List<User>`